# How to show offline Connection Error in UIWebView in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I want to show error to user when internet connection is offline in UIWebView.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) Class . Look the implement step from Andrew Zimmer answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk) that made in simple way.

For the modern development with ARC Mode. you can use [these project](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) that compatible with ARC Mode.

Good luck !